# How to fetch the contents within two line numbers using awk, with shell variables?

Tags: shell, awk

I want to fetch the lines within two line numbers, using **awk**:

```
startline=1
endline=12
location=$1
echo "awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" location="$location" \
          'NR>=$startline && NR<=$endline' $location"
awk_command=$("awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" \
                      location="$location" \
                   'NR>=$startline && NR<=$endline' $location")
```

...but this is not giving the expected response. Could you please help.

Thanks
Sushma

Comment: Do you give the file name in `$location`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have `$` in `awk` variable names.

```
awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' "$location"
```

Also you don't have to store the command in any variable.

```
!/bin/bash
startline=1
endline=12
location=$1
echo "awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' "$location""

# The line below is self sufficient.
awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' "$location"
#                                                        ^^^^ No '$' symbol in variable names
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try with sed :

```
sed -n "$startline,$endline p" "$location"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the awk command as a quoted string so you're not executing it. Change

```
awk_command=$("awk ... $location")
```

to

```
awk_command=$(awk ... "$location")
```

and then remove the `$`s to fix the variable access (**awk is NOT shell**) by changing:

```
awk_command=$(awk ... 'NR>=$startline && NR<=$endline' "$location")
```

to:

```
awk_command=$(awk ... 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' "$location")
```

I assume you already have `echo "$awk_command"` or similar after the above in your script!

Comment: Thanks.it works fine.. Is there a way to support this behaviour in both linux and solaris?

Comment: There is nothing about it that's non-portable. Just make sure on Solaris you're not using old, broken awk (/bin/awk) and use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead.

Comment: when i have tested the above thing in cygwin it works fine. but in solaris it is resulting in error.awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1  for the line awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' "$location" > log.txt

Comment: You **ARE** using old, broken awk on Solaris. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean input file for `awk` as `$location`, try this:

```
awk -v startline="$startline" -v endline="$endline" 'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' $location
```

Variables in `awk` do not need/use `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Two birds with one stone, (the variable *$awk_command* saves having to include the same line of code twice), and using the potentially dangerous **eval**:

```
startline=1
endline=12
test -r "$1" || exit 1 
location=$1
awk_command="awk -v startline=$startline -v endline=$endline \
            'NR>=startline && NR<=endline' $location"
echo $awk_command
awk_command_output=$(eval $awk_command)
echo "$awk_command_output"
```

Note the necessary inclusion of **test**:  *without* that, if some rascal set "*$1*" to `'filename ; evil ; deviltry ;'`, **eval** would slavishly go do `evil` and such.